# Android + Sqlite : Table creation sql has no effect

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a simple android application which creates a database using SQLiteDatabase (not using SQLiteOpenHelper). So the database creation and the table creation sql executes successfully without any issues/exceptions.

Now the issue is when I reopen the same database, the earlier table created does not exist!!

I am checking the existence of the table using the following code :

```
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+ sqlQueryString +"'", null);
                if(cursor!=null) {
                    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                        //error handling code here
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                }
```

Obviously am ending in the `if(cursor.getCount() == 0)` condition.

I pulled the db file and also checked with a [sqlite viewer](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlitetool/) on the pc, the table created earlier simply does not exist.

So my question is how do I verify that my create table query has created the table properly?

---

Adding requested information:

```
Create table ExampleTable ( ROWID integer primary key autoincrement , FIRSTNAME text    , LASTNAME text    ) ;
```

---

Adding the android code the execute the above query:

```
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL(sqlQueryString);
            db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE` query, and the code where you execute it.

Comment: you have to setTransactionSuccessful(), otherwise the transaction is rollbacked ... (as plainly stated in the beginTransaction documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` before you end the transaction, or else the operation is assumed to have failed and the transaction is rolled back.

Typical transaction usage is:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // execute DB queries here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

---

<sup>Credit to njzk2 for first mentioning the solution in a comment.</sup>